# brand new angular app - with angular material and ng serve blows up whenever I import a new module

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

This is Angular 9.
I run ng serve. things run fine at first, no components added yet.
Now, to so app.module.ts -> import any angular material component, doesn't matter which one.
add the import at the top.
add the module to the ngModule-> Imports.
go to app.component -> add a declaration. I just copy and paste the example for material web site for testing.
ng serve gives following error:
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/card/card-module.d.ts:8:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/material/card) which declares MatCardModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

8 export declare class MatCardModule {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Kill ng serve.
Run ng build
run ng serve -> now it works.

what is Ivy? How can I get it to work?

Comment: Do you use the latest version of Angular Material?

Comment: Ivy is the new renderer for Angular, details can be found here:
https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Comment: so why is it blowing up, I wonder? Brand new app out of the box and it doesn't work. Thanks for that link, I will try the enableIvy = False and see what happens this weekend.

Comment: enableIvy = false did not fix this.